# bxSLider not showing loading image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) to show my main page slide on a client's website. It works great and is a very nice feature packed, free, slide tool so I can't complain.

However, on the bxslide site they have loading panes show when an image isn't loaded. Once the image loads, it then shows the loaded image. On my site however, there is no loading image when the images aren't loaded and it's just collapsed on itself like you see in the image below until an image loads enough to fill the space

[image]

And then it just suddenly loads and there's an image like this

[image]

Why am I not getting the loading icon filling in that space when I am waiting for the image to load? Here is the jquery that I am using to call my slider currently

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    pause: 10000,
    speed: 2000,
    pager: false,
    useCSS: false
});
slider.goToSlide(1);
```

And the HTML for the slider

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" alt="Banner" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And finally here is a codePen with all of my css, since there is too much to post to SO.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aprBdK

Comment: I have a reasonable amount of experience with bxSlider, but your codepen needs to include the bxSlider JS library, and also some placeholder images. Try using http://placehold.it.

Comment: I updated the codepen to include the correct stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add the option `adaptiveHeight` to your `bxSlider` initialization.**

If there's no images loaded, the default settings for the slideshow are to have a height of 0. If you include the adaptive height property, the slideshow height will never be 0 (unless there really are no images in your slideshow).

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    pause: 1000,
    speed: 2000,
    pager: false,
    useCSS: false
});
slider.goToSlide(1);
```

Comment: I found this shortly after posting but thank you sir :)